# How to test the rescue block in my model callback in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have an after_save method in my model, to call some background task. Since this task is depending on another server being up, I thought it was a nice idea to create a fallback to perform the task on the main thread when the call to the other server fails.

This is basically the callback:

```
  def send_email
    MyJob.perform_async(self.id)
  rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    MyJob.new.perform(self.id)
  end
```

Now I'd like to test this bahavior. I tried by mocking the MyJob and raising the exception on the perfrom_async method. But how do I test that perform is being called on the instance?

I already tried:

```
it "should use fallback to send e-mail after create when faktory is down" do
  job = class_double("MyJob").
  as_stubbed_const(:transfer_nested_constants => true)

  allow(job).to receive(:perform_async) { raise Errno::ECONNREFUSED }
  expect_any_instance_of(job).to receive(:perform)
  company_opt_out
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to stub MyJob class

```
it "should use fallback to send e-mail after create when faktory is down" do
  allow(MyJob).to receive(:perform_async).and_raise(Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
  expect_any_instance_of(MyJob).to receive(:perform)
  company_opt_out
end
```

but make sure your `company_opt_out` calls `send_email` method

Answer (score 1):

Try to not overload the it block too much when you write the test as they become hard to read when you or another developer comes back to it later.

```
  let(:job_instance) { instance_double(MyJob, perform: "Performing now") }

  before do
    allow(MyJob).to receive(:perform_async).and_return("Performing later")
    allow(MyJob).to receive(:new).and_return(job_instance)
  end

  it "performs the job later" do
    expect(send_email).to eq("Performing later")
  end

  context "when a network error is raised" do
    before { allow(MyJob).to receive(:perform_async).and_raise(Errno::ECONNREFUSED) }

    it "performs the job now" do
      expect(send_email).to eq("Performing now")
    end
  end
```

Comment: nice solution, I'm still struggling with writing good tests, this makes a lot of sense though.

Comment: Only problem I still have is that `send_email` is a private method of the model used as an after_create callback. How should I be calling it, because send_email can;t be called from the test. Thanks

Comment: Then you can test the model the after save is a called on, or put this code into it's own class and test the class